# UICollectionView: make first item's width different from the rest

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, nscollectionlayoutsection

I'm currently trying to achieve the following layout using `NSCollectionLayoutSection`.  Do you have any advice on only **making the first item 50px wide while keeping the rest of the items 100px** (could be any number of items)? The solution has to be an `NSCollectionLayoutSection`.

[image]

I'm currently displaying them in the same width using which is not the desired result:

```
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)))
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                                 leading: 0,
                                                 bottom: 0,
                                                 trailing: 8)
    
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(100),
                                             heightDimension: .absolute(100)), subitems: [item])
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 16,
                                                   leading: 16,
                                                   bottom: 16,
                                                   trailing: 16)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
```

[image]

I've also tried using absolute widths but didn't have much luck with that approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating two separate item groups (one for the first cell which has a half width and second for the rest of the cells). Then combine those two groups and add it to the section.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let headerId = "headerId"
    let categoryHeaderId = "categoryHeaderId"
    let colorarray = [UIColor.yellow, UIColor.green, UIColor.green, UIColor.green, UIColor.green, UIColor.green, UIColor.green, UIColor.green]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "My Albums"
        collectionView.register(AlbumItemCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AlbumItemCell.reuseIdentifer)
        collectionView.register(CategoryHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: categoryHeaderId, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = createCompositionalLayout()
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    private func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionNumber, env) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            self.firstLayoutSection()
        }
    }
    
    private func firstLayoutSection() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        
        let cellWidth : CGFloat = 200
        let cellHeight : CGFloat = 200
        
        let smallItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(cellWidth/2), heightDimension: .absolute(cellHeight))
        let smallItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: smallItemSize)
        let smallGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(cellWidth/2), heightDimension: .absolute(cellHeight))
        let smallGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: smallGroupSize, subitem: smallItem, count: 1)
        smallGroup.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8)
        
        
        let largeItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(cellWidth), heightDimension: .absolute(cellHeight))
        let largeItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: largeItemSize)
        largeItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 8)
        let largeGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(CGFloat((cellWidth + 8) * CGFloat((colorarray.count - 1)))), heightDimension: .absolute(cellHeight))
        let largeGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: largeGroupSize, subitem: largeItem, count: colorarray.count - 1 )

        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(cellWidth * CGFloat(colorarray.count)), heightDimension: .absolute(cellHeight))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [smallGroup, largeGroup])
       
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging
        
        return section
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        colorarray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AlbumItemCell.reuseIdentifer, for: indexPath) as! AlbumItemCell
        cell.configure(color: colorarray[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

```
class AlbumItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
  static let reuseIdentifer = "album-item-cell-reuse-identifier"
  let view = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(color: UIColor) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(view)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        view.backgroundColor = color

    }
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Passing in the `count` param was the key. I totally missed that.